# What does encapsulating a function inside another function in onclick event actually mean?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I was studying JavaScript in W3Schools and I encountered with an expression like this:

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = function(){displayDate()};
```

On the right side of the equals sign, there is an anonymous function right? When we don't encapsulate the `displayDate()` function with an anonymous function it can clickable only once. When I clicked the button more than once it doesen't update the date. So what are the meaning of such functions in JavaScript? I am a real newbie. Can anyone give me a clear explanation about this method? **Encapsulating a function with an anonymous function in an onclick event.**

Comment: Well, the function expression evaluates to a function that you assign as a handler. If you do `= displayDate()`, that's not a function, you just call it once immediately (without any event involved yet). See also https://quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html#link2

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be strictly equivalent to the following:

```
document.getElementById('myBtn').onclick = displayDate;
```

because, for a function `displayDate` whose purpose is simply to display a date, the function `function () { displayDate(); }` should have the exact same effect as the function `displayDate` when you call it.

As a consequence, the problem of your date being updated only once should be unrelated to whether or not `displayDate` is wrapped in an anonymous function. You should look at your definition of `displayDate` to find the bug.

Comment: …except for the return value and the arguments and the `this` value

Comment: @Bergi Right, I was assuming in my head that "f" simply has side-effects and returns nothing, and doesn't make use of `this`, which would (certainly) be the case for a function called `displayDate` but certainly not for "any function" like I put it.

Answer (score -1):

This is what happens behind the scences: .onclick takes a function which is the callback function for the onclick event listener. As per definition a callback function should be equal to a function. In JS when you put =myfunction() you don't pass the function definition to the variable but what you are doing is passing the value of the execution of the function. So this should throw you an error since .onclick must take a function. To pass the definition of the function you remove the () or put it in function(){myFunc;}